# Continue from downloading folder

Tags: steam, payday-2

Last night I've been downloading Payday2 update. It was 5.3GB and requiring over 3 hours. So I decided keep turn on my laptop and sleep. I opened cmd (command.com) and entered command -shutdown -s -f -t 14400, which means my computer will shutdown after 4 hour by force. I thought its enough time. Then I just woke up. Turned on my laptop. Payday 2 5.3GB update downloading from start. It will now require over 4,5 hours again. When I go to steam's downlading folder there is 19.6 GB file. If it's complete can I use that? At least if not complete can I continue from there?
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuQPJ.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If that file is indeed Payday 2's partial download, Steam should automatically resume.  If it is not, there isn't anything you can do with it to "force" it to resume because you simply don't know what it is.

I have paused downloads during online play, forgot I paused it, shut off computer, and then find that it was partially downloaded the next time I start up Steam.

The second issue is the use of the -f tag in the shutdown command (this is getting into Super User domain here).  This is a FORCED shutdown, and it ungracefully kills running applications.  This command can shutdown Word with unsaved documents.  Steam most likely did not complete the shutdown properly and ended up with corrupted partial downloads, thus having to restart it again.

Comment: I checked that appID (see screenshot) from steamdb.info. 218620 is exactly Payday2's id.

Comment: @Gereltod Updated my answer.  The problem is most likely caused by -f.

Comment: I included -f on purpose. I already closed all my applications. Only steam was running. Thought just in case if steam or other useless software stuck on shutting down screen, it could be helpful. As I already said I entered enough time (4 hours). Mean time my download must have finished. Lets say something happened and couldn't finish. In that case it should continue from downloading folder right? Imagine electricity out and your computer shutdown (same as force). Steam still continues from dowloading.

Comment: Well, I guess Steam was "stuck" on shutting down to prepare for a download resume.  -f kills it and now it has to start over again.

Comment: Still there is 19 GB files already downloaded :( There must be way. At least I don't understand where is new fresh downloading files going? Overwriting them?

Comment: Whatever it is doing, you must let it complete on its own.  Steam has download resume algorithms to perform download resume, and if that has failed, then you basically need to REVERSE ENGINEER said system, FIX the partial file, and get STEAM TO RESUME.  It will take you a LOT longer than 5 hours to do this.

Comment: Steam should also detect already downloaded files, just let it run its 5GB download, it should skip files that exist.